# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 49: for textacy

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode, textacy

I am using the textacy method to get synonyms.

```
import textacy.resources
rs = textacy.resources.ConceptNet()
syn=rs.get_synonyms('happy')
```

I get the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj\Desktop\Work\QGen\lib\site-packages\textacy\resources\concept_net.py", line 353, in get_synonyms
    return self._get_relation_values(self.synonyms, term, lang=lang, sense=sense)
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj\Desktop\Work\QGen\lib\site-packages\textacy\resources\concept_net.py", line 338, in synonyms
    self._synonyms = self._get_relation_data("/r/Synonym", is_symmetric=True)
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj\Desktop\Work\QGen\lib\site-packages\textacy\resources\concept_net.py", line 162, in _get_relation_data
    for row in rows:
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj\Desktop\Work\QGen\lib\site-packages\textacy\io\csv.py", line 96, in read_csv
    for row in csv_reader:
  File "C:\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 49: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have tried to enforce encoding='utf8' in both concept_net.py", line 162,  and io\csv.py", line 96, in read_csv, but that gives another error

```
   raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "
EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

What can be done ?

Comment: maybe you have data with different encoding - ie, `Latin1`, `cp1250`, etc.

Comment: Where can I find that ? and how to change that ?